# React.js Redirect routing automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this piece of code in my `index.js` :

```
const routing = (
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route path='/'>
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    </div>
</Router>
)
```

So what it should give me is, whenever I start it, it should land on `http://localhost:3000/login` or somewhere like it. What it does.

It gives me a login screen, where if I click on *Login* button it takes me to `http://localhost:3000/home`, which is also as I intended.

But whenever I directly try to access `http://localhost:3000/home` or `http://localhost:3000/signin`, it always takes me to `http://localhost:3000/login`.

**What is the actual problem here? How this can be resolved ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `exact` on `<Route path='/'>` and `<Switch>` instead of  `<div>`:

```
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const routing = (
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
)
```

I think there will be problem with partial matching of path. When you try directly access `http://localhost:3000/home` first match in router is `/` and it redirects you to login.

When you use `exact` in `<Route>` it matches absolute path. In example above you will be redirected only when you access http://localhost:3000/

`<Switch>` groups and iterate `<Router>` children elements and renders first match.

In your case (without `<Switch>`) it's rendering all `<Routes>`. Therefore is probably triggered redirect.

Comment: Doesn't work. please see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SPgHqj3P-7GVBWiyKLdboA5Mj5t8X7Lk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I know it is improbable but cannot be problem with single quotation marks in `<Route exact path='/'>` ?

Comment: what about `<Switch>` from 'react-router-dom' instead of `<div>`

Comment: Edited. I am glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the keyword `exact` to your routes to specify specific route paths according to the URL, or it will follow the line of succession. For example, if you visit the URL `/` it will load the login component as expected because that is the first route. However, if you visit the URL `/home` it will render the login component because it contains the path `/`. Adding the `exact` keyword means ONLY the URL `/` will hit that route. Any other routes, even if they contain `/` (which is every route) will not render that component because `/` is not the EXACT same route as `/anything`.

```
const routing = (
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. please see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SPgHqj3P-7GVBWiyKLdboA5Mj5t8X7Lk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It looks like it's working fine when you login and can see the home page. The issue comes when you refresh the browser. I'm assuming you have authentication methods already because you're handling the `onClick` for login. Perhaps when you refresh the page, you are losing that authentication which is why you are forced to the login page again? It doesn't seem to be an issue with the `Router` itself.

Comment: But, currently there is no authentication method, I am just using `<Link>` and playing around.